# How to generate a regex to capture everything but curly brace contents

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match strings of any size NOT surrounded with { and } as in foo{bar} the regex should match foo but not {bar}.

The regexes I originally came up with were `^([^${].*[}$])` and `^(?=[{]).+(?<=[}])` but they don't seem to do what I expected them to do.

Comment: abc{pq}d what should be output ? abcd ?

Comment: We dont know enough about your source string. Will it always be like `foo{bar}` for the full string, or can it be like `foo{bar}foo` or `foo{bar}foo{bar}`? What should the output be for those?

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt Yes, the output in your case should be abcd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch all the characters that is not within {} then you can attempt an split operation using regex.

Split the string by this regex by using your preferred language:

{.*?}

The returned array should consist the segments that was found outside each {}

The following java example returns an array (arr):

```
String abc="19{22}33{44}55{66}7";
String[] arr=abc.split("\\{.*?\\}");
```

which contains:

```
["19","33","55","7"]
```